# Using a custom controls DLL in a Windows Forms C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop, ms-forms

We are migrating a VBA application to a Windows Forms C# application. The old VBA application used a custom controls DLL provided by vendor. How do we use such controls (I guess MSForms) with Windows Forms?

We managed to find an interop DLL in vendor's binaries and link it to the Visual Studio solution, but the control classes are obviously incompatible with Windows Forms.

Comment: Those are entirely different technologies. Talk to your vender to see if they support WinForms. If not, realistically you're probably out of luck. As an aside, WinForms is quite old. If you're starting from scratch you might want to work with something newer.

Comment: WinForm should be dead by now it still exists because of old apps ... newer implementation should consider newer UI framework such as [avaloniaui](https://avaloniaui.net/) it's similar to WPF but cross-platform

Comment: What do you mean by "control classes are incompatible with Windows Forms"? Do you get an error message etc.? Can you give more information please?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I can instantiate the object without errors, but I don't know how to put it on the form. It doesn't have the Location property because the class doesn't inherit from the Windows Forms Control class.

Comment: Regarding the selection of Windows Forms, it's a revival of an old project, so we have to stick with Win Forms in this version.

Comment: I can just assume what you call "custom" means its an ActiveX control then start reading the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-activex-controls-to-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: [Windows Forms ActiveX Control Importer (Aximp.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/aximp-exe-windows-forms-activex-control-importer) can also be useful.